# Spilling water to keyboard fixes keyboard weird

Tags: keyboard

I have a laptop of about 5-6 years old.

(A) key hasn't working properly for a while.

But I spilled water on down arrow key and weirdly (A) key started working.

How is this possible?

Comment: How did you dry the keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely because many keyboards use membrane's with contacts under the keys which when you press a key, it joins those 2 contacts together sending a signal that the key has been pressed.

Over time, the contacts wear out or get dirty and no longer work or work intermittently.

The chances are, the water you spilled either added enough conductivity to the contacts that made the key appear to work or its washed some dried dirt out of the contact allowing the key work again.

Comment: weird thing is i not spilled water to (A) key i spilled on down arrow key.

Comment: The spilled water closed a connection between two of the paths. When you know how those membranes' keyboards are inside, it isn't weird at all.

Comment: Keyboards generally use a row and column system, so the water may have re-connected a failed row or column which included the A key.